# how to send value using intent in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

```
    Login.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val id = ID.getText().toString()
        val pw = Password.getText().toString()
        val responseListener =
            Response.Listener<String?> { response ->
                try {
                    val jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
                    val success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success")
                    if (success) {
                        val msg = jsonObject.getString("nickName")
                        val userInd = jsonObject.getString("userInd")
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "success. ID :$msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,LoginActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("UserInd",userInd)
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "UserInd: $userInd")
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        return@Listener
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "except 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return@Listener
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        val loginRequestActivity = LoginRequestActivity(id, pw, responseListener)
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
        queue.add(loginRequestActivity)
    })
```

in MainActivity.kt
and 
`val intent = intent val UserInd: String? = intent.getStringExtra("UserInd") Log.d("BookInsertActivity", "UserInd: $UserInd")` in BookInsert.kt 
 in MainActivity server send userInd print **UserInd:1** successfully but send value by using intent to BookInsert 
 BookInsert.kt print **UserInd:null**

 how to fix it ?

Comment: In code you mention `val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)` `LoginActivity` but while get value from intent you mentioned `BookInsert.kt`, Both are same activity or different? If different then you should change `Activity` name in `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

If the userInd is an integer (integer), you should also get it of the correct type when retrieving it. For example:

```
val UserInd: Int = intent.getIntExtra("UserInd",0)
```

Comment: i fix like this answer. but only print 0. but in MainAcitivy print "UserInd = 1"

Comment: Here '0' defaultValue represents the default value to be used when a value associated with the UserInd key is not found. You can determine this value as you wish. For example, it can be 0 or another numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(Intent(requireContext(), YourDesireActivity::class.java).putExtra("key", value))
```

And get the Value

```
var variableName = intent.getStringExtra("key") as? String
```